# AOS Animate - отключение на мобильных устройствах

Tags: javascript, jquery, animate

Я подключал библиотеку анимации AOS Animate. Как можно отключить все анимации на мобильных устройствах меньше < 576px?

Comment: Код в студию (html, js, css)!

Comment: https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/ библиотека aos animate. анимация добавляется с помощью атрибутов (data-aos="fade-up"). скрипт подключается    AOS.init();          я попробовал как в документации    AOS.init({disable: mobile,});  но тогда вместе с анимацией пропадает и сами блоки

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте эту информацию в вопрос. Также хорошо было бы пример использования увидеть.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте подключать эту библиотеку и ваш код, который к ней относится, только с определённой ширины экрана.

```js
var width = $(window).width();
 console.log(width);
    if(width >= 576){
      ***
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: не могу, так как анимации добавляются с помощью атрибутов к html тегам. пример:  <div class="hero-img" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1000" data-aos-once="true">
                <img src="images/elements/macbook.png" alt="">
            </div>

Comment: И что? Если вы отключите библиотеку с вашими дата атрибутами ничего не случится, как и с HTML в целлом

Answer (score 1):

Лишние классы в css не повредят, я надеюсь, а скрипт и стили `aos` по условию можно добавить вот так:

```
if (window.innerWidth > 576) {

  var s = document.createElement("script");
  s.setAttribute('src','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aos/2.3.4/aos.js');
  document.body.append(s);

  var l = document.createElement("link");
  l.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
  l.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
  l.setAttribute('href', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aos/2.3.4/aos.css');
  document.head.append(l);
}
```

Comment: А как отключать потом?)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko потом это после 8 марта? )

Comment: Нет, конечно. После нового года! Все обновялется в новом году....

Answer (score 1):

@Stranger in the Q ваш ответ решил задачу но не полностью, на десктопе были проблемы с анимацией, я совместил ваш ответ с другим методом все работает отлично:
Добавил ID к тегу link где подключался css file и удалил на мобильном:

```
if (window.innerWidth < 576) {

  function removeAos() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('aos-css-file');
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    return false;
  }
  removeAos();

}

AOS.init();
```